# Use list names inside purrr:::map_dfr function

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I was trying something relatively simple, but having some struggles. Let's say I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`:

df1:

```
id  expenditure
1    10
2    20
1    30
2    50
```

df2:

```
id  expenditure
1    30
2    50
1    60
2    10
```

I also added them to a named list:

```
table_list = list()
table_list[['a']] = df1
table_list[['b']] = df2
```

And now I want to perform some summary operation through a function and then bind those rows:

```
get_summary = function(table){
   final_table = table %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(total_expenditure= sum(expenditure))

}
```

And then apply this through `map_dfr`:

```
summary = table_list %>% map_dfr(get_summary, id='origin_table')
```

So, this will create a almost what I'm looking for:

```
 origin_table   id   total_expenditure
      a          1       40
      a          2       70
      b          1       90
      b          2       60
```

But, what if I would like to do something specific depending on the element of the list that is being passed, something like this:

```
get_summary = function(table, name){
   dummy_list = c(TRUE, FALSE)
   names(dummy_list) = c('a', 'b')

   final_table = table %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(total_expenditure= sum(expenditure))

   is_true = dummy_list[[name]] # Want to use the original name to call another list

   if(is_true) final_table = final_table %>% mutate(total_expenditure = total_expenditure + 1) 

   return(final_table)

}
```

This would bring something like this:

```
 origin_table   id   total_expenditure
      a          1       41
      a          2       71
      b          1       90
      b          2       60
```

So is there any way to use list names inside my function? Or any way to identify which element of my list I'm working with? Maybe `map_dfr` is too restricted and I have to use something else?

Edit: changed example so it is more grounded in reality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `map`, use `imap`, which can return the names of the list in `.y`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
get_summary = function(dat, name){
   dat %>%
       group_by(id) %>%
        summarise(total_expenditure= sum(expenditure, na.rm = TRUE), 
              .groups = "drop") %>%
        mutate(total_expenditure = if(name=='a')
                total_expenditure + 1 else total_expenditure)

}
```

-testing

```
> table_list %>% 
    imap_dfr(~ get_summary(.x, name = .y), .id = 'origin_table')
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  origin_table    id total_expenditure
  <chr>        <int>             <dbl>
1 a                1                41
2 a                2                71
3 b                1                90
4 b                2                60
```

#### data

```
table_list <- list(a = structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), 
expenditure = c(10L, 
20L, 30L, 50L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L)), 
    b = structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), expenditure = c(30L, 
    50L, 60L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -4L)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it, by adding `origin_table` as a pre-existing column on the dataframes:

```
df1 = df1 %>% mutate(origin_table = 'a')
df2 = df2 %>% mutate(origin_table = 'b')
```

Then I can extract the origin by doing the following:

```
get_summary = function(table){
   dummy_list = c(TRUE, FALSE)
   names(dummy_list) = c('a', 'b')

   origin = table %>% distinct(origin_table) %>% pull

   final_table = table %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(total_expenditure= sum(expenditure))

   is_true = dummy_list[[origin ]] # Want to use the original name to call another list

   if(is_true) final_table = final_table %>% mutate(total_expenditure = total_expenditure + 1) 

   return(final_table)

}
```